# RatingBar not scaling correctly for lower resolutions after Nougat

Tags: android, android-widget, rating, ratingbar, rating-system

I have a standard android RatingBar that is working correctly on multiple android screen sizes with multiple android versions.  However, I have a user that has Samsung S7 (7.0).  There is an option in the device settings to reduce the screen resolution under Settings/Display after Nougat.  When the screen resolution is reduced from the standard 2560 x 1440 to 1920 x 1080 or 1280 x 720 the stars in the RatingBar do not resize and become quite large.  How do I get the stars to resize appropriately?  Screen captures are shown below with a problem at the 1920 x 1080 resolution.

[2560x1440 resolution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EW6O5.jpg)

[1920x1080 resolution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/js3hb.jpg)

```
   <RelativeLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

    <Button
        android:text="Add Data"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button_add"

        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:id="@+id/scrollview"
        android:layout_above="@id/button_add"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">


            <TextView
                android:text="Stress"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:paddingStart="@dimen/tab_label"
                android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.DeviceDefault.Large"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/rbStress"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/rbStress"
                android:layout_below="@+id/textView6" />

            <TextView
                android:text="Breathing"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/textView4"
                android:paddingStart="@dimen/tab_label"
                android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.DeviceDefault.Large"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_above="@+id/rbCough"
                android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/rbBreathing"
                android:layout_below="@+id/rbAbdomen" />

            <TextView
                android:text="Chest Pain"
                android:paddingTop="5dp"
                android:layout_width="200dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:id="@+id/textView3"
                android:paddingStart="@dimen/tab_label"
                android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.DeviceDefault.Large"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_above="@+id/rbAbdomen"
                android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/rbChest" />

            <TextView
                android:text="Abdomen"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:id="@+id/textView"
                android:paddingStart="@dimen/tab_label"
                android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.DeviceDefault.Large"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_above="@+id/rbBreathing"
                android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/rbAbdomen"
                android:layout_below="@+id/rbChest" />

            <TextView
                android:text="Stress"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/textView7"
                android:paddingStart="@dimen/tab_label"
                android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.DeviceDefault.Large"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/rbStress"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/rbStress"
                android:layout_below="@+id/textView6" />

            <TextView
                android:text="Dizzyness"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/textView6"
                android:paddingStart="@dimen/tab_label"
                android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.DeviceDefault.Large"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_above="@+id/rbStress"
                android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/rbDizzy"
                android:layout_below="@+id/rbCough" />

            <TextView
                android:text="Cough"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/textView5"
                android:paddingStart="@dimen/tab_label"
                android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.DeviceDefault.Large"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_above="@+id/rbDizzy"
                android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/rbCough"
                android:layout_below="@+id/rbBreathing" />

            <RatingBar
                android:paddingTop="5dp"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/rbChest"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.RatingBar" />

            <RatingBar
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/rbAbdomen"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_below="@+id/rbChest"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.RatingBar" />

            <RatingBar
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/rbBreathing"
                android:layout_below="@+id/rbAbdomen"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.RatingBar" />

            <RatingBar
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/rbCough"
                android:layout_below="@+id/rbBreathing"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.RatingBar"/>

            <RatingBar
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/rbStress"
                android:layout_below="@+id/rbDizzy"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.RatingBar"/>


            <RatingBar
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/rbDizzy"
                android:layout_below="@+id/rbCough"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.RatingBar" />

        </RelativeLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the behaviour you are describing is part of the new [accessibility features](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/nougat/android-7.0-changes.html#accessibility). So all you can do is follow the advice they are giving there: test expressly for smaller screens etc.

You may consider providing different resources (layout files, drawables,...) for different screen sizes, and it might be a good idea to make the stars smaller, as I think the top priority should be the users being able to read the text. Or you could come up with a different type of rating indicator which takes less room, like just one big star, maybe partly colored, and something like (3/5) beside it.

Comment: I didn't want to develop resources for all the screen sizes.  Rather, I wanted to use the "stock" android rating bar.  Is there any other way besides making my own "rating bar"?   Won't everyone have this problem if they try to use the stock rating bar?